# Is there a 'lazy map'?

Tags: scala

Just like `Stream` is a lazy `Seq`, is there a lazy version of `Map`?

What I want to do:

```
val lm = LazyMap[Int, String]((a) => {
  println("only once")
  (a * a).toString()
})
lm.get(10) // print "only once"
lm.get(10) // print nothing
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are basically asking for a cache.
You might have a shot at using `scalaz.Memo`, which adds memoization to a given function.
See http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Memo.html

This would give something like:

```
val lm: Int => String = Memo.mutableHashMapMemo[Int, String] { a =>
  println("only once")
  (a * a).toString()
}
```

Note however that what you get is a function, not a map. This means that you cannot test for the presence or absence of a given key, you can only apply. 
But if I am to trust your example, in your case this is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 12):

[`mutable.Map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Map) provides the method `getOrElseUpdate(key: A, op: ⇒ B): B`. You could use that to implement lazy semantics.

You should wrap the class in another class though, because else the value can be changed later by anyone who has the reference to that map.